# regex to detect string separated by non alphabet characters (or nothing)

Tags: r, regex

I'd like to write a regex to detect the string "el" (stands for "eliminated" and is inside a bunch of poorly formatted score data).

For example

```
tests <- c("el", "hello", "123el", "el/27")
```

Here I'm looking for the result `TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE`.  My sad attempts which don't work for obvious reasons:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(tests, "el")  # TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
str_detect(tests, "[^a-z]el")  # FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex `(\\b|[^[:alpha:]])el(\\b|[^[:alpha:]])` along with `grepl`:

```
> tests <- c("el", "hello", "123el", "el/27")
> y <- grepl("(\\b|[^[:alpha:]])el(\\b|[^[:alpha:]])", tests)
> y
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Your condition for whether `el` appears as an entity is that both sides either have a word boundary (`\b`) or a non alpha character (represented by the character class `[^[:alpha:]]` in R).

Comment: I think yours is safer depending on what op wants, for example `grepl("(\\b|[^[:alpha:]])el(\\b|[^[:alpha:]])", "123el27")` and `!grepl("\\wel\\w", "123el27")` give different results